# How to force Matlab to read files in a folder serially?

Tags: matlab, directory, dir

I have files in a folder that are numbered from `writer_1` to `writer_20`. I wrote a code to read all the files and store them in cells. But the problem is that the files are not read serially.

```
folders = dir(Path_training);
folders(ismember( {folders.name}, {'.', '..'}) ) = []; %Remove these two from list
training = [];
    for i = 1:length(folders)
        current_folder = [Path_training folders(i).name '\']; 
.
.
.
.
.
```

Here `folders(1).name` is writer_1 and `folders(2).name` is writer_10

I know that `dir` will return its results as the explorer does but is there any way to force it to go numerically?

I'm training an SVM based on these numbers and this problem is making it difficult.

Comment: Can't you do `list = dir(folder)` and `sort(list)`? Then it would only be the question of the desired sorting criterion.

Comment: If you can rename the folders, the easiest solution would be to name them writer_01, writer_02... so that they will automatically sort correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

```
%// From your code
folders = dir(Path_training);
folders(ismember( {folders.name}, {'.', '..'}) ) = []

%// Convert folders struct to a cell array with all of the data from dir
folders_cellarr = struct2cell(folders)

%// Get filenames
fn = folders_cellarr(1,:)

%// Get numeral part and sorted indices
num=str2double(cellfun(@(x) strjoin(regexp(x,['\d'],'match'),''), fn(:),'uni',0))
[~,ind] = sort(num)

%// Re-arrange folders based on the sorted indices
folders = folders(ind)
```

**Approach #2**

If you would like to avoid `struct2cell`, here's an alternative approach -

```
%// Get filenames
fn = cellstr(ls(Path_training))
fn(ismember(fn,{'.', '..'}))=[]

%// Get numeral part and sorted indices
num=str2double(cellfun(@(x) strjoin(regexp(x,['\d'],'match'),''), fn(:),'uni',0))
[~,ind] = sort(num)

%// List directory and re-arrange the elements based on the sorted indices
folders = dir(Path_training);
folders(ismember( {folders.name}, {'.', '..'}) ) = []
folders = folders(ind)
```

Please note that **[`strjoin`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html)** is a recent addition to MATLAB Toolbox. So, if you are on an older version of MATLAB, here's the [source code link](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31862-strjoin) from MATLAB File-exchange.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any direct solutions to the problem you are having.
I found a solution for a problem *similar* to yours, [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/33722-the-problem-about-dir-function)

```
List = dir('*.png');
Name = {List.name};
S = sprintf('%s,', Name{:});    % '10.png,100.png,1000.png,20.png, ...'
D = sscanf(S, '%d.png,');       % [10; 100, 1000; 20; ...]
[sortedD, sortIndex] = sort(D); % Sort numerically
sortedName = Name(sortIndex);   % Apply sorting index to original names
```

Differences are:

1. You are dealing with directories instead of files
2. Your directories have other text in their names in addition to the numbers

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different way (edited to fix bug and implement suggestion of @Divakar to eliminate for loop)

```
folders = dir(Path_training);
folders(ismember( {folders.name}, {'.', '..'}) ) = [];

%// Get folder numbers as cell array of strings
folder_nums_cell = regexp({folders.name}, '\d*', 'match');

%// Convert cell array to vector of numbers
folder_nums = str2double(vertcat(folder_nums_cell{:}));

%// Sort original folder array
[~,inds] = sort(folder_nums);
folders = folders(inds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Stealing a bit from DavidS and with the assumption that your folders all are of the form "writer_XX" with XX being digits.

```
folders = dir([pwd '\temp']);
folders(ismember( {folders.name}, {'.', '..'}) ) = [];

% extract numbers from cell array
foldersNumCell = regexp({folders.name}, '\d*', 'match');

% convert from cell array of strings to double
foldersNumber = str2double(foldersNumCell);

% get sort order
[garbage,sortI] = sort(foldersNumber);

% rearrange the structure
folders = folders(sortI);
```

The advantage of this is that it avoids a for loop. In reality it only makes a difference though if you have tens of thousands for folders. (I created 50,000 folders labeled 'writer_1' to 'writer_50000'. The difference in execution time was about 1.2 seconds.

Comment: Don't you need `str2double(vertcat(foldersNumCell{:}))` instead?